# Using the Path.lineTo to increase by a decimal in the x axis

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, floating-point, scale

I want to draw a signal waveform using the path.linTo method and a for loop as shown below.

```
public void drawSignal(Canvas c, PointF pos) // draws the signal onto the Canvas for each of the 12 channels
{
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);

    Path path = new Path();

        for (int i=0; i<ECGFilereader.numChannels; i++){
            path.moveTo(wavePos[i].x, wavePos[i].y);

            for (int chan = 0; chan<ECGFilereader.numChannels; chan++)

                for (int m = 0; m < ECGFilereader.numSamples; m++){

                    path.lineTo(m+wavePos[i].x, signal[chan][m]+wavePos[i].y);
            }
        }

            c.drawPath(path, paint);
```

However I would like to scale the graph so that each movement in the x-axis is only 1/5 of that of the y-axis, so that the length of the signal is effectively squashed horrizontally. Is it possible to do this by simply using floats somehow I do I need to actually create a larger canvas and scale it there?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

err, either multiply the y-components by 5 or divide the x-components by 5 in both path.moveTo and path.lineTo?

Comment: Yeah of course, sorry was being stupid and just trying to make things far more complicated than they needed to be. In actual fact I just needed to divide m by 5 for the x co-ord in the path.lineTo. Thanks